# When can the moment generating function be differentiated to find moments?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable and suppose
$$\phi(t):= E[e^{tX}] $$
exists for all $t$. For simplicity, suppose $\phi$ is infinitely differentiable on the whole real line. An easy exercise, using the mean value theorem and dominated convergence theorems, is that if $E[Xe^{tX}] < \infty$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\phi'(t) = E[Xe^{tX}]$. Of course, then taking $t = 0$ recovers our favorite formula $\phi'(0) = E[X]$.

To use the dominated convergence theorem, however, we needed to assume $E[Xe^{tX}] < \infty$, which may be hard to prove for a given random variable $X$.

> Are there cases where $\phi(t)$ and $\phi'(t)$ exist and are finite, but $E[Xe^{tX}] = \infty?$

My motivating question is that the Laplace transform of the hitting time $T_m = \inf(t : W_t = m)$ of standard BM $W_t$ is
$$E[e^{-\alpha T_m}] = e^{-|m|\sqrt{2\alpha}}$$
for $\alpha > 0$.To compute $E[T_m]$, one differentiates both sides to obtain
$$E[T_m e^{-\alpha T_m}] = \frac{|m|}{\sqrt{2\alpha}} e^{-|m|\sqrt{2\alpha}}$$
and uses the monotone convergence theorem to send $\alpha \downarrow 0$ and conclude. But apriori, how did we know the derivative of $E[e^{-\alpha T_m}]$ was $E[T_m e^{-\alpha T_m}]$, moreover that the latter even exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $Ee^{tX} <\infty $ for all $t$ then $EXe^{tX} <\infty $ for all $t$ because $xe^{tx} \leq e^{(1+t)x}$ for all $x \geq 0$. In fact, with no further assumption, $EX^{n}e^{tX} <\infty $ for all $n$ and $\phi $ is automatically infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Cool! So is it right to say that if an MGF exists in a ngbd of 0, then the r.v. has $n$ moments if and only if the MGF is $n$ times differentiable?

Comment: Yes, that statement is correct.