# Differentiating under expectation operator

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This is a follow-up on [differentiating the mgf to find moments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842571/when-can-the-moment-generating-function-be-differentiated-to-find-moments/2842576?noredirect=1#comment5862193_2842576).

Let $g(t,x)$ be a smooth function and $X$ be a random variable. Set $f(t) = E[g(t,X)]$. If $g_t(t,X)$ is dominated by an $L^1$ random variable, then one can show $f$ is differentiable.

> Is there an example of a random variable $X$ and smooth $g(t,x)$ such that $f(t) = E[g(t,X)]$ is finite and smooth for all $t$ but $E[g_t(t,X)] = \infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be a standard normal, and let
$$g(t,x) = \exp(-(t e^{x^2}-1)^2)$$
$$g_t(t,x) = (2-2te^{x^2})\exp(-(t e^{x^2}-1)^2+x^2)$$
$$g_t(0,x) = (2/e)e^{x^2}$$

Then $g(t,X)$ has finite expectation, since $g(t,x)\le 1$, but $g_t(0,X)$ has infinite expectation.

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=contour%20plot%20of%20Exp(-(t%20Exp(x%5E2)-1)%5E2)%20on%20-2%3Cx%3C2,%20-1%3Ct%3C3) is the contour plot of $g$, with white regions near 1 and red regions near 0.

[image: contour plot]

Comment: I awarded bounty without realizing this, but is $E[g(t,X)]$ smooth in $t$? This was a critical hypothesis

Comment: I think E[g(t,X)] is smooth everywhere except at t=0.

Comment: Welp, that was a sad waste of 50 reputation points.